# How to get value from a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I have this class:

```
public class CustomerFilter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
public class Search
{
    private Expression<Func<CustomerFilter, bool>> customerfilter;

    public Expression<Func<CustomerFilter, bool>> CustomerFilter
    {
        set { customerfilter = value; }
    }
}

var search = new Search();
search.CustomerFilter = (x => x.Id == 1);
```

From within the search class, how can I get the value of a property without using `ExpressionVisitor`? Something like:

```
var customerId = customerFilter.Id; //Or something similar
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't really understand why do you need it. But, you could do something like that:

```
public class Search
{
    private Expression<Func<CustomerFilter, bool>> customerfilter;

    public Expression<Func<CustomerFilter, bool>> CustomerFilter
    {
        set { customerfilter = value; }
    }

    public object GetValue(CustomerFilter filter)
    {
        var property = (customerfilter.Body as BinaryExpression).Left;
        var lambda =Expression.Lambda(property, customerfilter.Parameters.First());
        return lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke(filter);
    }
}
```

With such usage:

```
var search = new Search();
search.CustomerFilter = (x => x.Id == 1);
var filter = new CustomerFilter {Id = 12};
search.GetValue(filter).Dump();
```

I get `12` as output

Comment: You're getting the value from a new instance of `CustomerFilter`. I need to get the value from the expression itself.

Comment: Expression doesn't have any instance, you could build a new expression, that gets value, but you need an instance to apply it

Answer (score 2):

If your `CustomerFilter` only support `MemberExpression==ConstantExpression` like in your sample code. Then you could get the information directly from the `Expression` object.

```
var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)((BinaryExpression)customerfilter.Body).Left).Member.Name;
var propertyValue = ((ConstantExpression)((BinaryExpression)customerfilter.Body).Right).Value;
```

If you want to support more complicated expressions, `ExpressionVisitor` should be use to parse the `expression` tree.

Comment: that gives right value of the expression. In sample of the answer it is 1. I don't think it is what OP wanted. Otherwise what he wants, if i understand it right is not possible.

Comment: Keep in mind that this introduces a restraint on the possible lambda expressions which may be easy to overlook for others (or you after some time). You may want to add a check in the setter of `CustomerFilter` to make sure that the given expression is in the supported form.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit misleading that you have a class and a property `CustomerFilter` which represent very different things. As I understand it, the class would better be named `Customer`:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

public class Search
{
    private Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> customerfilter;

    public Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> CustomerFilter
    {
        set { customerfilter = value; }
    }
}

var search = new Search();
search.CustomerFilter = (x => x.Id == 1);
```

Then it is more obvious that there is no property `customerFilter.Id` in your `Search` class. You only have an expression which can take any(!) `Customer` and convert it to a `bool`. It does so by comparing the `Customer.Id` to a given value, but `Search` does not know about that.

If you need to get the comparison id in `Search`, I suggest you change the type of the `CustomerFilter` property to a class which has a public `ComparisonId` property and generates the filter expression based on that id:

```
class CustomerIdFilter // note: this will not replace your existing CustomerFilter which I have renamed to Customer
{
    public CustomerIdFilter(int id){ ComparisonId = id; }
    public int ComparisonId{ get; private set}
    // To filter use this
    public bool IsValid(Customer c){ return c.Id == ComparisonId; }
    // or maybe something similar to this, if necessary
    public Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>FilterExpression
    {
        get
        {
            return (x=>x.Id == ComparisonId);
        }
    } 
}
```

You code would change to s.th. like this then:

```
public class Search
{
    private CustomerIdFilter customerfilter;

    public CustomerIdFilter CustomerFilter
    {
        set { customerfilter = value; }
    }
}

var search = new Search();
search.CustomerFilter = new CustomerIdFilter(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Going a step further based on xwlantian's answer, I did the following and it works for simple expressions:

```
var value = Expression.Lambda(((BinaryExpression)customerFilter.Body).Right).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```